# Has anyone successfully used a BLE113 with the Android native libraries in Kit Kat?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

We are having difficulty with Android 4.4.2 native libraries connecting with our custom characteristics on our BLE113 enabled device. We were able to read these values using the Motorola libraries until they vanished and also from Windows and Mac.

I'm looking into the issue now, but was simply wondering if anyone else had seen the same thing.

Comment: Try scanning the devices without a service udid filter, and filter it on your own. It's a known bug that custom service / characteristic will not report.

Answer (score 0):

We have had may trials and tribulations with the Android BTLE support. We initially wanted to support Android 4.3, but ran into numerous issues with bonding and security.

It seems that 4.4.2+ is stable and working on almost all devices, however we have had issues with the Moto G - our only Motorola test device at the moment. The Moto G would not routinely bond and encrypt the connection to the BLE113. Every other attempt would result in a connection, but no bonding, or a bond without encryption. Upgrading the Moto G to 4.4.4 fixed any issues that we had.

Here's our setup, as it may have similarities to your own.

- Custom GATT profile
- Encrypted read and write characteristic
- Just works / No Keyboard No Display bonding
- Bonding is required on the BLE113 however Android and iOS initiate the bonding, security and bonding are NOT initiated from the BLE113 peripheral.